# Errno 111 Connection refused when installing ibm_db behind corporate proxy (DB2 with Python3)

Tags: python, proxy, pip, db2

I'm trying to install the [`ibm_db` python package](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) in a corporate network behind our proxy server. Even with the `--proxy` switch (which is a local squid connecting to the corporate proxy in my case) I get ean error cause the package seems to download dependencies by executing python code:

```
$ pip3 install --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128" ibm_db
Collecting ibm_db
  Using cached ibm_db-3.0.3.tar.gz (794 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cd295_i4/ibm-db/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cd295_i4/ibm-db/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-cd295_i4/ibm-db/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cd295_i4/ibm-db/
    Complete output (44 lines):
    Detected 64-bit Python
    Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1350, in do_open
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1417, in connect
        super().connect()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 921, in connect
        self.sock = self._create_connection(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I guess the the `proxy` switch doesn't get forwarded to the python call inside. [An older issue from  2018](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/304#issuecomment-367372531) recommends to download it manually and set `IBM_DB_HOME` as env variable, which seems worked for him.

```
export IBM_DB_HOME=/home/myuser/Downloads/db2_py/
```

Now I got another error:

```
$ pip3 install --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128" ibm_db
Collecting ibm_db
  Using cached ibm_db-3.0.3.tar.gz (794 kB)
ERROR: Files/directories not found in /tmp/pip-install-a0t600_t/ibm-db/pip-egg-info
```

Seems like there are some additional files required. I also tried to download the archive from pypi.org and install it using `pip3 install <path-to-downloaded-archive>`. But this doesn't help, since the dependencies are not included there.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a real solution yet, but a workaround to get the package installed:

1. [Download the python package from pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/#files)
2. Extract it
3. In the extracted archive, open `setup.py` and open `setup.py`
4. Before `PACKAGE = 'ibm_db'`, insert the following lines, where `127.0.0.1:3128` is your proxy server:

   ```
   os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:3128/'
   os.environ['https_proxy'] = os.environ['http_proxy']
   os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = os.environ['http_proxy']
   os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = os.environ['http_proxy']
   ```
5. Install the package with the manipulated `setup.py` file:

   ```
   $ pip3 install --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128" /home/myuser/Downloads/ibm_db2_extracted/ibm_db-3.0.3/
   ```

Now the installation works, cause the proxy is set for the entire python environment instead of just pip. However, this is not an optimal solution because we have to apply this workaround on every update, but a suiteable short-term solution until we find something better.